# code for json listview throwing error

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I wanted to print the json data retrieved from database in listview so that it will be in readable format for the app user. But the following error is obtained:

```
07-20 18:22:09.541 29095-29095/com.example.manv.nokialabs I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.manv.nokialabs time:36794948

                                                                      --------- beginning of system
07-20 18:22:09.591 29095-29095/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/var32: [{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5784818bcb30b4918964b50f"} , "LabLocation" : "LSD-SRN-BLR-U02" , "RackLocation" : "SRN-Radio-B01" , "ShelfLocation" : "SH-01" , "fourBid" : "908762" , "Cluster" : "Radio" , "fourBookingName" : "BTS01-Coral-SRN-BLR" , "SoftwareVersion" : "LN6.0" , "HardwareType" : "FRGP" , "AssetNo" : "40824873" , "SerialNO" : "RY114208612" , "Location" : "zzccg" , "Uname" : "addtvI"}]
07-20 18:22:09.591 29095-29095/com.example.manv.nokialabs D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                            --------- beginning of crash
07-20 18:22:09.592 29095-29095/com.example.manv.nokialabs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.manv.nokialabs, PID: 29095
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.manv.nokialabs/com.example.albbaby.nokialabs.DisplayListView}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.example.albbaby.nokialabs.DisplayListView.onCreate(DisplayListView.java:32)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) )
```

Here is my code:

```
public class DisplayListView extends AppCompatActivity {
    String json_string;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    dataAdapter dataAdapter;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.displaylistview_layout);
        listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        dataAdapter=new dataAdapter(this,R.layout.row_layout);
        json_string=getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");
        Log.w("var32",  json_string);
        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(json_string);

            jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("_id");
            int count=0;
            String LabLocation,RackLocation,ShelfLocation,fourBid,Cluster,fourBookingName,SoftwareVersion,HardwareType,AssetNo,SerialNo;
            while (count<jsonObject.length()){
                JSONObject JO=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                LabLocation=JO.getString("LabLocation");
                RackLocation=JO.getString("RackLocation");
                ShelfLocation=JO.getString("ShelfLocation");
                fourBid=JO.getString("fourBid");
                Cluster=JO.getString("Cluster");
                fourBookingName=JO.getString("fourBookingName");
                SoftwareVersion=JO.getString("SoftwareVersion");
                HardwareType=JO.getString("HardwareType");
                AssetNo=JO.getString("AssetNo");
                SerialNo=JO.getString("SerialNo");
                data data=new data(LabLocation,RackLocation,ShelfLocation,fourBid,Cluster,fourBookingName,SoftwareVersion,HardwareType,AssetNo,SerialNo);
                dataAdapter.add(data);
                count++;
            }

        }catch (JSONException e){
            Log.w("var33", "error JSON exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help to debug.
Thanks

Comment: So, the error you're getting back is tring to call "org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)" on a null reference object.  Double check your code and make sure that all of your objects are initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your onCreate Method by Below it will work

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.displaylistview_layout);
       listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
       listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
       dataAdapter=new dataAdapter(this,R.layout.row_layout);
       json_string=getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");
       Log.w("var32",  json_string);
       try {
           jsonArray = new JSONArray(json_string);
           int count=0;
           String LabLocation,RackLocation,ShelfLocation,fourBid,Cluster,fourBookingName,SoftwareVersion,HardwareType,AssetNo,SerialNo;
           while (count <  jsonArray.length())
          {
               JSONObject JO=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
               jsonObject = JO.getJSONObject("_id");


               LabLocation=JO.getString("LabLocation");
               RackLocation=JO.getString("RackLocation");
               ShelfLocation=JO.getString("ShelfLocation");
               fourBid=JO.getString("fourBid");
               Cluster=JO.getString("Cluster");
               fourBookingName=JO.getString("fourBookingName");
               SoftwareVersion=JO.getString("SoftwareVersion");
               HardwareType=JO.getString("HardwareType");
               AssetNo=JO.getString("AssetNo");
               SerialNo=JO.getString("SerialNo");

              data data=new data(LabLocation,RackLocation,ShelfLocation,fourBid,Cluster,fourBookingName,SoftwareVersion,HardwareType,AssetNo,SerialNo);

              dataAdapter.add(data);

              count++;
           }

       }catch (JSONException e){
           Log.w("var33", "error JSON exception");
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake is first line of try block 
you code:

```
 jsonArray = new JSONArray(json_string);
```

It should be  :

```
    jsonObject = new JSONArray(json_string);
```

Thats why error is coming

Comment: You meant to change to `jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string); ` ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is fixed after adding the below code:
`

```
try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(json_string);
            jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("arrayName",jsonArray);
            jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("arrayName");
            int count=0;
            String LabLocation,RackLocation,ShelfLocation,fourBid,Cluster,fourBookingName,SoftwareVersion,HardwareType,AssetNo,SerialNO;
            while (count<jsonObject.length()){
                JSONObject JO=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                LabLocation=JO.getString("LabLocation");
                RackLocation=JO.getString("RackLocation");
                ShelfLocation=JO.getString("ShelfLocation");
                fourBid=JO.getString("fourBid");
                Cluster=JO.getString("Cluster");
                fourBookingName=JO.getString("fourBookingName");
                SoftwareVersion=JO.getString("SoftwareVersion");
                HardwareType=JO.getString("HardwareType");
                AssetNo=JO.getString("AssetNo");
                SerialNO=JO.getString("SerialNO");
                Log.w("var34",  "Arguments Passed");
                data data=new data(LabLocation,RackLocation,ShelfLocation,fourBid,Cluster,fourBookingName,SoftwareVersion,HardwareType,AssetNo,SerialNO);
                dataAdapter.add(data);
                count++;
            }
```

`